# Checking validity of argument in compareTo?

Tags: c#

If I had this class that implementing IComparable:

```
public class BankAccount : IComparable<BankAccount>
{
    [...]

    public int CompareTo(BankAccount that)
    {
        if (this.Balance >  that.Balance) return -1;
        if (this.Balance == that.Balance) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Should I check if `that` is null. Also, should I check if `that` actually is of type `BankAccount`? If for some reason, it is best to type check, then why? I mean C# is statically typed and in my case, `BankAccount` is not a base class.

Comment: Checking that `that` is null should be done, preferably by throwing an ArgumentNullException when it's null

Comment: Also, you could have just used `return this.Balance.CompareTo(that.Balance);` (although that `this` is useless)

Answer (score 1):

> Should I check if that is null

Yes you should and if null probably throw some exception.

> Also, should I check if that actually is of type BankAccount

Why? since you are using a strongly typed version of IComparable `IComparable<T>`

You can as well use `Comparison<T>` delegate instead of providing a `IComparable<T>`